# ¿Existe una forma de prevenir el copiado en un excel solo para algunas columnas?

Tags: excel, vba, apache-poi

Hay alguna forma de que los valores de una columna no sean copiables en excel?.

Intenté que la columna no sea seleccionable y la protegí con contraseña, pero aún así se pueden copiar los valores al seleccionar las columnas de los lados.

Creo que la solución podría ser a nivel de código VBA o de algún otro procesador de archivos excel, como Apache POI.

Comment: Faltó indicar lo que se ha buscado/investigado sobre el tema. A este fecha, la pregunta ya cuenta con una respuesta, sería adecuado que la aceptaras o incluyeras algún comentario acerca de la misma, ¿te sirvió?

Answer (score 2):

Se puede deshabilitar el copiado desde VBA con [Application.CutCopyMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/office/ff839532.aspx).

Para ir permitiendo o no que se copie, tenemos que cambiar esta propiedad cada vez que cambia la selección actual. En el código de una hoja:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    'especificamos un rango prohibido de ejemplo 
    Dim RangoProhibido As Range
    Set RangoProhibido = Range("A1:C6")

    'Verificar que la selección actual no tenga celdas dentro del rango prohibido (vemos la intersección)
    If (Application.Intersect(Target, RangoProhibido) Is Nothing) Then
        'permite copiar
        Application.CutCopyMode = True
    Else
        'no se puede copiar
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
End Sub
```